# Условия при анимации контрола

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть `radiobutton` с кастомным стилем, в котором есть заданный через стиль XAML прямоугольник с именем `rectangle`.
Хочу сделать так, что бы при наведении мышки на `radiobutton`, прямоугольник плавно менял свой цвет, но только в том случае, если `radiobutton`не выбран (`IsChecked = False`).
Использую код

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Duration="0:0:0:0.5"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(Color)"
                To="#5d4037">
            </ColorAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Возможно, мне стоит сделать проверку через код (C#)? Если да, то как это сделать?

Попробовал сделать через код

```
ColorAnimation aRadioEnter = new ColorAnimation();
Color color1 = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("##5d4037");
aRadioEnter.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
aRadioEnter.To = color1;
//
Storyboard Storyboard;
Storyboard = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.Children.Add(aRadioEnter);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(aRadioEnter, target.Name);
```

но не знаю, как указать цель (прямоугольник `Rectangle`) через `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty`.

И вообще, как получать доступ к элементам контрола через код? Например, если мне нужно поменять цвет заполнения прямоугольника `Rectangle`.

Comment: Ещё раз переспрошу: зачем вам наследоваться от `RadioButton`'а? Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Да не зачем. Плохая была идея, сейчас использую обычный radiobutton с кастомным стилем. Однако вопрос остается в силе. Просто теперь суть вопроса - как запускать анимацию через код и как добавлять анимацию на свои элементы (которые в контроле) через код.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужен code-behind. У меня сработало такое:

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SB">
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Duration="0:0:0.5"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(Color)"
            To="#5d4037"/>
    </Storyboard>
</ControlTemplate.Resources>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                         Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                         Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="BeginMouseEnterSB" Storyboard="{StaticResource SB}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginMouseEnterSB"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <!-- ... -->
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

`EventTrigger`'у нельзя установить условие, берите `DataTrigger` (в нашем случае — `MultiDataTrigger`).